# Скрытие клавиатуры и перенос каретки в EditText

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Нужно при нажатии "Enter" скрыть клавиатуру. Всё работает, но при закрытии клавиатуры каретка переходит на новую строку. Как убрать перенос строки при закрытии?

```
msg.setOnKeyListener(View.OnKeyListener { v, keyCode, event ->
            if (event.getAction() === KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                when (keyCode) {
                    KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER ->
                       hideKeyboard()
                    else -> {
                    }
                }
            }
            false
        })

private fun hideKeyboard(){
        val imm = getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(etMessage.windowToken, 0)
    }
```

Comment: Попробуйте возвращать `true` в ветке когда обработали enter. То есть после `hideKeyboard()`.

Comment: @eugeneek Может есть вариант через xml? Заменить Enter на ОК?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно и через xml. Нужно добавить следующий параметр к `EditText`:

```
<EditText
    ...
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    ...
    />
```

Comment: Да, но распространяется только на android:inputType="text"

Comment: Ну вообще-то нет. Работает со всеми `inputType`, кроме `...MultiLine`, что логично.

Comment: хм...важное замечание.

Answer (score 1):

```
 msg.setOnKeyListener(View.OnKeyListener { _, keyCode, event ->
            if (event.action === KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                when (keyCode) {
                    KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER ->
                        hideKeyboard()
                }
            }
            true
        })
```